# How to call output of a php page in an html page in a specific div?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

This is my html code

```html
<html>
<body>
<form name="form1" action="php1.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="text1">
<input type="submit" name="submit1">
</form>
<div id="div1">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my php1.php code

```html
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit1']) && ($_POST['text1'])=="text"){
echo "hello";
}
?>
```

If I want to call the output of php1.php i.e., hello, in html div1 what to do ?

@Uzumaki, I've edited my html code like this, but its not working, here is my code.

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
$("form#postit").submit(function(){

                                var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "hello.php",
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    data: formData,
                                    async: false,
                                    success: function (data) 
                                   {

                                        // $("#div1").append(data); // or 

                                        $("#div1").html(data);

                                    },
                                    cache: false,
                                    contentType: false,
                                    processData: false
                                });
                        return false;
                    });
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="form1" method="post" id="postit">
  <input type="text" name="text1">
<input type="submit" name="submit1">
</form>
<div id="div1">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You have to make a AJAX Request either using Javascript or JQuery.

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_aspphp.asp

Comment: There are several answers.  Mine is the naive answer and works if you want one HTML/PHP combo page.  If you need to run the PHP independently of the (original) HTML page, you'll need to look at the other answers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you didn't mention via jquery or ajax I am assuming you are going with a simpler old fashioned way So here is the code

**SEND YOUR MESSAGE BACK TO HTML PAGE LIKE THIS**

```
$msg = "hello"
header("Location: your_html_page.html?msg=".$msg);
```

**IN HTML DO THIS**

```
<div id="div1">

<?php
error_reporting(0);
echo $_GET['msg'];

?>

</div>
```

**USING JQUERY :**

**Post the data to php**

```
$.post("your_php_page.php",{data:data},function(returned_data_from_php){

$("#div1").append(returned_data_from_php); // or 

$("#div1").html(returned_data_from_php);

});
```

**Using Ajax**

```
$("form#postit").submit(function(){

                                var formData = new FormData($(this)[0]);

                                $.ajax({
                                    url: "your_php_page.php",
                                    type: 'POST',
                                    data: formData,
                                    async: false,
                                    success: function (returned_data_from_php) 
                                   {

                                         $("#div1").append(returned_data_from_php); // or 

                                         $("#div1").html(returned_data_from_php);

                                    },
                                    cache: false,
                                    contentType: false,
                                    processData: false
                                });
                        return false;
                    });
```

**PHP**

what ever you want to return from php it should be echo and there are many ways to do that

(Single string)  `echo "Success";`

(Multiple Strings) `echo $msg1.$msg2;`

(Array data)
for example ...

```
$data = array();
$i = 0;
while($numbs = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$row_numb = $numbs['id'];
$data[$i] = $row_numb;
$i++;
}

    echo json_encode($data);
```

// this will pass a json type object to the java script

When you get to javascript you want to access all the elements of the array one by one well that's easy too

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
parsed_it = JSON.parse(data); // data is the json type you got from your php
```

so `parsed_it[0],parsed_it[1],parsed_it[2]` and so on you can access all the data

hope it helps !!

Comment: Actually its a small version of my php code in question. I've lots of outputs in that php file. I want every output in the php1.php file to be displayed in the div1. How to do it, instead of calling and sending each message manually...?

Comment: Please mention both the methods...with ajax as well as jquery...it will be very helpfull to me.

Comment: @PrakashPatil I have edited my answer all you need to know about posting the data to php and getting it back .... feel free to ask anything else concerned...

Comment: please look at my other question...How to show data on <select> options..can you help ?

Comment: share the link to your question

Answer (score 1):

Put the PHP into your HTML file where you want the result.  Be sure your file is named `something.php` and that you have a PHP processor on the server.

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="form1" action="php1.php" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="text1">
<input type="submit" name="submit1">
<div id="div1">
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit1']) && ($_POST['text1'])=="text"){
    echo "hello";
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Actually it was just a short form of my original php code. I've lots of outputs on the php page. I want to call all the outputs to the html page in div1. How to do ?

Comment: The same way.  Just put your PHP where you want the output on the HTML form.

Answer (score 0):

You may use AJAX to dynamically load script output:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/tryit.asp?filename=tryajax_get

You may also consider using jQuery to simplify your code:

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/